# How do I extract specific cells in a row in a table to populate another table if a value in the first table is greater than 0?

Tags: microsoft-excel, worksheet-function

So the title might sound strange, but I will try to explain.

Say I have "Table A" and "Table B". Table A contains multiple rows and columns with item numbers, amount of each item, name of the item and so on, and Table B has the same columns but is otherwise empty.

If I change the value in the cell under "amount" in Table A to something greater than zero, part of that row will be added to Table B, and if I change it back to zero in Table A, the row will be deleted in Table B.

I can't for the life of me figure out how to do this, if it's even possible at all. I have read other topics that sound similar, but unfortunately they don't really help with what I am searching for.

If anything is unclear or if you need more information, please let me know.

Comment: Is it possible to provide a sample file or screenshots about this problem?

Answer (score 0):

Use Power Query for this.

Put your cursor in Table A and click **Data - Get & Transform - From Table** from the ribbon. (If Table A is not actually a table yet, this will be done for you and make sure that the "My table has headers" checkbox in the "Create Table" dialog box is selected.)

You should see Table A's information in a new "Power Query Editor" window.

In the Power Query Editor, filter the amount column to only show values greater than 0, then change the query name (in the right sidebar) to "Table B".

Look good? Great. Click **Home - Close & Load** from the ribbon. Unless you've changed your power query settings, this will create a new worksheet in your Excel file with Table B on it.

When you make changes in A then you can right-click in Table B and refresh, or click **Data - Refresh All** in the ribbon to refresh Table B. Unfortunately, if you want to do it automatically you'll have to write some VBA for this. Hopefully, manually refreshing is acceptable.